# How to convert a String that looks like JSON or a JS object, to an actual JS object?

Tags: javascript, json, string, javascript-objects

The String I am talking about was initially a part of a JS object like:

```
var nameVal = "Jacob";
var favNumbersVal =  "{\"firstNum\":0, \"secondNum\":1, \"thirdNum\":2}";

var aJSObject = {
    "name" = nameVal,
    "favNumbers" = favNumbersVal
};
```

The variable I am interested in is **`favNumbersVal`**. Please notice that the starting and ending `"` around the value of `favNumbersVal` are the normal double quotes we put around a String whenever we define a String.

The format of the value of favNumbersVal is coming from a library dynamically.

**The question is that how do I convert the value of `favNumbersVal` to a JS object,** so that when I later convert `sJSObject` to JSON using `JSON.stringify()`, the value of `aJSObject` becomes a JSON object, and the value of `favNumbers` becomes a JSON object nested inside the aforementioned JSON object.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
var favNumbersVal =  "{\"firstNum\":0, \"secondNum\":1, \"thirdNum\":2}";
console.log(JSON.parse(favNumbersVal));
```